# Auto-Deploy from Gitlab to Server results in an empty folder

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

**The issue**
I'm trying to deploy a single static page on my Linux Server (Debian 9.5 with VestaCP) using a gitlab runner. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQbENcbPtDo) and even though everything goes fine (the job is marked as "Passed" either on commit or when I manually run the task), the final result is that the destination folder (/web/bue.nico.ar/public_html/testgit) is actually empty.

**.gitlab-ci.yml file content**

```
stages:
  - deploy
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - if ["$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" == "master"]; then cp -R ./web/bue.nico.ar/public_html/testgit; fi
```

**Output from Gitlab**
 [image: Screenshot from Gitlab output]

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have some syntax errors in `script` which throws the following error:

```
bash: line 93: [master: command not found]
```

To get rid of the above error and possible upcoming errors:

1. Add white spaces between brackets and condition (this is the root cause for the mentioned error)

```
if ["$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" = "master"] ===> if [ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" = "master" ]
```

2. Please change operator `==` to `=` for checking the equality of two strings (probably `==` is not a valid operator in Bash scripts).
3. Command `cp` is used for copying a source path to a destination. you just specified a single path.

‌I suggest you consider GitLab CI/CD's [`rules:if`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) as an alternative, like the following:

```
stages:
  - deploy
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'

  script: "cp -R  ...  ..."
```

If the provided rule does not match, the job is set to `when: never` and is not included in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it's not working. Tried switching the `==` for `=` and the mentioned error and the empty folder still occurs, even when the job is still marked as passed. Also tried your suggested alternative and even though the job is marked as passed, I get the same result in the job output and a warning message from the Gitlab IDE: "This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: root config contains unknown keys: deploy".

Comment: Sorry! I should have read your CI/CD job more carefully. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm getting new a new error and a failed deploy now: "cp: missing destination file operand after './web/bue.nico.ar/public_html/testgit/*'" I found a possible solution by adding a "/*" at the end of the path but the same error occurs. The syntax of the .yml file is marked as valid on Gitlab, although it seems that something must be missing which makes the deploy to fail.

Comment: If you check my answer again, in case number 3 I mentioned that command `cp` must used with two paths. The first one for source and the second for destination. You just gave only one path and also the second path is required. So please provide it.  YAML validator never checks validation of commands which used in `script` part of every job.

Comment: Thanks for your patience man, it seems that the tutorial I've followed was missing a couple of things. I'm trying to figure out what the source path should be. If I'm hosting the repo on Gitlab, what would be the source path of it? Just an example of the last line of the script would be super helpful.